# Firefox slow with javascript running off the hard-drive, not with uploaded files

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm currently developing a javascript-based game engine. I'm running it off my local drive because reuploading every single small change to a webserver takes too much time.

The local copy runs fine in Chrome (with the --allow-file-access-from-files parameter), but in Firefox (v19) the engine slows down massively. The website itself loads fully, but any movement or clicks react very slowly until the script crashes. Clearing cache or closing tabs doesn't make it go any faster.

When I upload the site to a server however, it runs just fine in Firefox.

I've tried disabling security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy in my dev-profile. It makes it a little faster, but doesn't solve all the slowdowns.

Is there a known issue with local javascript running slower in Firefox?

Comment: I've never heard of any known issues (can't imagine why there would be?) but have you checked Firebug's error consol? You could be throwing an error that's bugging it out.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of testing your code on a `file:` URL, why not use a local web server? Then everything should run the same as it would on any other web server, and you will be able to test your app in all browsers without fiddling with their security settings.

What OS are you running? You can easily install [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) on any of the popular OSes. On Windows, some people prefer [Uniform Server](http://www.uniformserver.com/). On OSX you can use XAMPP or the built-in web server.

Then just save your files in your local web server's `htdocs` directory as you would on any other server, and load your app from either a `localhost:` URL, or better yet, use your own machine's hostname with a `whatevermyhostnameis:` URL, to avoid any special security treatment that localhost may receive.

Comment: I had already considered that, but I was hoping for an easier solution. XAMPP still gives me extra steps before I see my result. I'm also rather interested why Firefox is exhibiting this behaviour.

Comment: What extra steps are you thinking you'd have with XAMPP? The workflow is identical to loading from a file: URL. Simply develop directly in a subdirectory of XAMPP's htdocs. Then you just save a file and refresh the browser, the same as you're doing now. There's no uploading or any other steps.